# Laravel: Column not found when using "WithCount"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to order by using following priority:

1. Show casts first having given city
2. Show casts first having given prefecture
3. Display remaining casts which does not have provided city or prefecture

My database table structure is:

Casts:

```
id
...
...
shop_id
```

Shop:

```
id
..
..
```

Location

```
id
city
prefecture
```

Available Location

```
id
location_id
shop_id
..
```

In order to filter the cast from city/district,

1. It first needs a shop
2. Shop needs available_location
3. Available_location is then filtered from the location's city or district

For that scenario, I have used the following condition:

```
$casts = Cast::filterNonBusy()->attendancePresent()->where('is_deleted', 0)->with('review', 'castImage', 'shop', 'shop.location');
        if (isset($request->city) || isset($request->prefecture)) {
            $city = $request->city;
            $prefecture = $request->prefecture;

            $locationHavingCityIds = Location::where('city', $city)->pluck('id')->toArray();
            $locationHavingPrefectureIds = Location::where('prefecture', $prefecture)->pluck('id')->toArray();

            if (!empty($locationHavingCityIds)) {
                $casts = $casts->withCount(['shop', 'shop AS has_filtered_city' => function ($shopQuery) use ($locationHavingCityIds) {
                    return $shopQuery->whereHas('availableLocations', function ($availableLocationQuery) use ($locationHavingCityIds) {
                        $availableLocationQuery->whereIn('location_id', $locationHavingCityIds);
                    });
                }])->orderBy('has_filtered_city', 'DESC');
            }

            if (!empty($locationHavingPrefectureIds)) {
                $casts = $casts->withCount(['shop', 'shop AS has_filtered_prefecture' => function ($shopQuery) use ($locationHavingPrefectureIds) {
                    return $shopQuery->whereHas('availableLocations', function ($availableLocationQuery) use ($locationHavingPrefectureIds) {
                        $availableLocationQuery->whereIn('location_id', $locationHavingPrefectureIds);
                    });
                }])->orderBy('has_filtered_prefecture', 'DESC');
            }
        }
```

If the cast has related city, it gives me has_filtered_city as 1.
Else it gives me has_filtered_city as 0

And I ordered according to the has_filtered_city.

The problem occurred when the cast has no associated city, it gives me an error with:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'has_filtered_city' in 'order clause' (SQL: select `casts`.*,
> `cp`.`cast_id`, `cp`.`depreciated_price` from `casts` inner join
> `cast_prices` as `cp` on `cp`.`cast_id` = `casts`.`id` and `cp`.`id` =
> (select id from cast_prices cp1 WHERE cp1.cast_id = casts.id ORDER BY
> depreciated_price DESC LIMIT 1) where `is_published` = 1 and
> (`busy_till` is null or `busy_till` < 2020-12-09 04:26:15) and not
> exists (select * from `reservations` where `casts`.`id` =
> `reservations`.`cast_id` and (`status_id` = 1 or `status_id` = 2)) and
> exists (select * from `attendances` where `casts`.`id` =
> `attendances`.`cast_id` and `attendance_status` = 1) and `is_deleted`
> = 0 and exists (select * from `cast_prices` where `casts`.`id` = `cast_prices`.`cast_id` order by `name` asc) and (not exists (select *
> from `reservations` where `casts`.`id` = `reservations`.`cast_id`) or
> (select count(*) from `reservations` where `casts`.`id` =
> `reservations`.`cast_id` and `status_id` = 5) < 3) and `is_published`
> = 1 order by `has_filtered_city` desc, `has_filtered_prefecture` desc, `depreciated_price` desc limit 20 offset 0)

Where did I go wrong in has_filtered_city? It sometimes work perfectly but sometimes throws as error saying "Unknown Column: has_fiiltered_city".

Comment: The error message provides the query text. It does not contain the reference to `has_filtered_city` and `has_filtered_prefecture` columns except final ORDER BY really.

Comment: If I do something like: `$casts->first()->has_filtered_city;` , it displays me the value but it is not working in orderBy.

Comment: *it is not working in orderBy.* Try to use positional specification. For example, if you select this column as 3rd in the output structure then `ORDER BY 3 DESC` will sort by this column.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using whereHas inside whereHas (nested) gave problem of column not found for withCount. During these scenario, it is wise to use innerJoin and select the desired column and filter using that column.

```
$casts = $casts->select('casts.*', 'calc_c.cast_id', 'calc_c.max_loc')->join(DB::raw("
            (SELECT casts.id AS cast_id,
                    casts.NAME,
                    casts.shop_id,
                    cal.max_loc
                    FROM casts
                    INNER JOIN (SELECT Min(CASE
                    WHEN al.city = '{$city}' THEN 1
                    WHEN al.prefecture = '{$prefecture}' THEN 2
                    ELSE 3
                    END) AS max_loc,
                    al.shop_id
                    FROM (SELECT available_locations.location_id,
                    available_locations.shop_id,
                    locations.prefecture,
                    locations.city
                    FROM available_locations,
                    locations
                    WHERE available_locations.location_id =
                    locations.id) al
                    GROUP BY al.shop_id) cal
                    ON casts.shop_id = cal.shop_id
                    ORDER BY casts.id ASC) AS calc_c"), 'casts.id', '=', 'calc_c.cast_id');

                $casts = $casts->orderBy('max_loc', 'ASC');
```